# Why logging via slf4j will lead to starvation?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I read this from [10 Tips for Proper Application Logging](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html):

> Another side effect is slowing the application down. Quick answer: if
>   you log too much or improperly use toString() and/or string
>   concatenation, logging has a performance side effect. How big? Well, I
>   have seen server restarting every 15 minutes because of a thread
>   starvation caused by excessive logging.

And this:

> SLF4J will call toString() only when the statement is actually
>   printed, which is quite nice. But if it does… Out of memory error, N+1
>   select problem, thread starvation (logging is synchronous!), lazy
>   initialization exception, logs storage filled completely – each of
>   these might occur.

So my question:

1. What is the really synchronous thing in `logging is synchronous`, call `toString()` or `I/O` or some other issue in logging?
2. Why synchronous logging will lead to starvation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means, that the call to `logger.log(...)` will only return AFTER the log message has been written to whatever output is specified. There are options and implementations, which do this step asynchronously, returning immediately after the call. IIRC, logback has this.
2. If you log too much, the thread will be busy with executing the logging statements and won't execute anything else. This is, why the logging frameworks try to do their things as effective and efficient as possible, e.g. by only evaluating the log message formatting when the logging is actually done. Earlier, this was done by encapsulating the logging statement into an `if` clause:

   ```
   if (log.debugEnabled()
       log.debug("some Message " + withAnIntensiveToStringCall());
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just have one more question: If a thread call `log.info(aObject)`, could another thread read or write to `aObject`?

Comment: `There are options and implementations, which do this step asynchronously, returning immediately after the call.` This thread will return immediately, but I think there must be another thread to do the work(write it to somewhere). So, if you do so much log, all of the thread may busy with logging. So The same result with synchronous one?

Comment: Yes, calling the toString() method - assuming, no setter/write is called within that - does not block calls to other methods. So it _could_ be possible, that there is concurrent access, although that access would have happened without the logging as well. Hence, either it is allowed and accounted for or it is a bug which would have occured anyway.